# Old DB name in information schema prevents viewing relationships

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL DB running on WAMP, accessed via PHPMyAdmin. After various bits of tinkering, the DB was renamed and tables moved in and out of it. My issue now is that for one table in particular, when I click on 'Relation View' it returns an error:

```
SQL query: 
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `OLD_DB_NAME`

MySQL said: 
#1049 - Unknown database 'OLD_DB_NAME'
```

So I assume the old DB name is hanging around somewhere in the Information schema. I've looked in the various @TABLE tables there, but see no mention of that name. I can see the table in question with the proper schema assigned. Where else could it be?

Comment: 1) The database name is a name of a subdirectory in the datadir directory where the files of this database are placed into 2) The database must be correctly registered in system dictionary database. *So I assume the old DB name is hanging around somewhere in the Information schema.* INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not real database, it is a bunch of pre-defined system views which retrieves the data from system databases and functions dynamically. It even have no according directory in the datadir, rather than, for example, PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA..

Comment: @Akina What then do you suggest I do?

Comment: Try the next. Create new database with any name. Create the tables in this database with the same structures. Stop server. Replace tables files with your actual ones. Start server. Execute REPAIR TABLE on each table. Then check does the tables are accessible w/o errors and all data is available and consistent, if so then rename database.

Comment: phpmyadmin also has its own set of metadata tables. I would check if something is cached there.

Comment: @Akina I created a tmp DB and dumped a backup DB in there. Then I dropped the original, and renamed the tmp. Wasn't your solution, but it solved the problem. For the reference of others, if you want to propose your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Oh, did you have a backup? I thought you only had the tables files themselves.